# Making a div the size of window in Dash

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

I'm trying to build a website using Dash. Now I'm facing problems while making the layout using a css file I made. I wanted to make a container (a div) as large as the window (100% height, 100% width), but for some reason it won't work.

I have set all parent elements (html, body) to `height: 100%; width: 100%`, but when I make a border around the first div, it's really small and has 0 height, but 100% width.

I thought, maybe there is a parent div or some other parent element I haven't seen so far, that I haven't made as high as the window. Maybe someone knows if there is a element I have to set to full height. I also don't know, if the `html` and `body` selector works, because I don't see any `html` or `body` in the Dash app.

I have a multi-page-app, so there is my index.py:

```
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

from app import app
from apps import home, about

app.title = "Wetter"
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content', className="all")
], className="all")


@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              Input('url', 'pathname'))
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/home' or pathname == '/' or pathname == '/home/':
        return home.layout
    elif pathname == '/about' or pathname == '/about/':
        return about.layout
    else:
        return '404'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

My home app:

```
layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        # ------------- First part -------------
        html.Div(
            children=[
                # ------------- Title on left side -------------
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.H1(children="Wetter", className="header_title"),
                        html.P(
                            children="some text",
                            className="header_description",
                        ),
                    ],
                    className="header",
                ),

                """ some other code following """

            ],
            className="upper_part"
        ),
    ],
    className="all",
)
```

The start of my css file:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.all {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

/* ------------ First part of page ------------ */

.upper_part {
    background-color: #222222;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    verticalAlign: middle;
    textAlign: center;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

/* ------------ Header ------------ */

.header {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #222222;
    margin: 0;
    verticalAlign: middle;
}

.header_title {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.header_description {
    color: #CFCFCF;
    margin: 4px auto;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 384px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `vw` and `vh` instead

> vw is equal to one percent of the viewport width, meaning that if you set your font size using vw, it will always relate to the size of the viewport.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design

So you could do something like this:

```
.all {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}
```